# Joomla Contact Form (from the ground up)

Tags: forms, joomla, contacts

I'm looking to create a customized contact form in a Joomla 3 site I have created. I know how to write the php code for the form, but I'm unsure of where to place the code.

Ok, the form is located at http://www.theoscorner.com/contact-us. What you see there is only the design, and there is currently no script for the form to submit to. If I wanted to create a new php page for the form to submit to, what is the best method of doing this? For example:

1. Should I create a completely new php file where the template's index.php file sits, and use a module (instead of an article) to hold the form.
2. Should I create a new article page, and place my php script in that article?
3. Should I hard-code my form into a module, and place a php function at the end of the index.php page which gets called when the page is refreshed and the POST values are set.

I'm just looking for any type of guidance I can get right now. I don't want to use a third-party plugin, because I want a little more control than they allow. Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component or https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use RS Forms or Contact Enhanced, they are both Joomla extensions available on extensions.joomla.org

There is no need to create your own MVC component.